# How get self parameter of other class?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to reuse my code, I have 30 files that use the same hub progress this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let hub = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    hub.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
    self.view.addSubview(hub) // starts loader
    // some code
    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true) // stop loader
}
```

Then I dont know how I can do this in one util swift file generic like:

```
class Loader{

    func start(){
      // the start code
    }

    func stop(){
      // the stop code
    }

}
```

To do just

```
var load = Loader()
load.start()
// some code
load.stop()
```

I guess that my problem is acess the self of the actual class from other, how can i do this?

Comment: If you always use this in a ViewController, consider extending the UIViewController class with this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the view into the `Loader` class which will get you access to the view that you need to add it to.

```
class Loader{

    func start(view: UIView){
        let hub = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(view, animated: true)
        hub.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
        view.addSubview(hub) // starts loader
    }

    func stop(view: UIView){
        MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(view, animated: true) // stop loader
    }

}

....
var load = Loader()
load.start(self.view)
// some code
load.stop(self.view)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case `extension` is the best approach. Its very simple and not need to allocate loader class in every viewcontroller again again. Just put this code out of the scope any of your class and use with out any complexity.

```
extension UIViewController{
  func start(){
    MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
  }

  func stop(){
    MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Call from your ViewController like this:

```
self.start()

.....

self.stop()
```

Comment: Though, I like Chris approach better, as it follows the Single Responsibility Principle, your idea is although good — except that after 2 weeks I wouldn't know what `start()` would trigger.

Comment: It's a good way of do too, but I have one question, if i do extension in one file, all others file will receive this extension ?